# Show that the number or $r$ combinations of $X$ which contain no consecutive integers is given by $\binom{n-r+1}{r}$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, contest-math, combinations

Let $X=\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$ where $n\in N$. Show that the number or $r$ combinations of $X$ which contain no consecutive integers is given by   $\binom{n-r+1}{r}$ where $0\le r\le n-r+1$.

I am unable to think of any possible way to prove it.

Please explain the proof and comment on the technique used to help me with problems in the future.

Thanks in Advance!

**Thanks for pointing the typing faults!**

Comment: In the current form, it seems like $X$ consists of all positive integers. Do you maybe mean $X = \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$?

Comment: What do you mean by “$r$ combinations of X”?

Comment: @user218931 I mean like if i take r elements of X at a time.

Comment: @Dominik yes I do mean $X = \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$. I missed the n.

Comment: @HeinzKloube So you mean without repetition?

Comment: The formula is wrong. For $r = n > 1$ there is no way to choose $r$ elements from $X$ that aren't consecutive. Maybe the formula is supposed to be $\binom{n - r + 1}{r}$? I didn't check if this yields the correct formula, but it fits the trivial cases.

Comment: @user218931 The question don't state anything of it. But since it said r combinations so with repetitions it is.

Comment: @Dominik $0\le r\le n-r+1$

Comment: I wonder can you use an induction argument on $n$ - it should be fairly easy to prove the formula for $n=1$, and then consider choices from $X=\lbrace 1,2,...,n,n+1 \rbrace$ containing $n+1$ and not containing $n+1$

Comment: I still cannot make any sense of it. If we take $X = \{1,2,3\}$ and $r=2$, then $\binom{n+r-1}{r} = \binom{4}{2} = 6$ but the only combinations I can find are $(1,1)$, $(2,2)$, $(3,3)$ and $(1,3)$ (and possibly $(3,1)$ if the order is important), so only 4 (or 5) combinations, but not 6… Someone please clarify?

Answer (score 4):

The formula you originally gave (now corrected) was wrong.

Consider $n$ unnumbered balls and take out $r$ of them, leaving behind $(n-r)$

The $r$ balls taken out can be re-inserted in any of $(n-r+1)$ spaces between the balls left behind (including the ends) in ${n-r+1\choose r}$ ways.

*Now* number the balls. ${n-r+1\choose r}$ enumerates all possible combos of $r$